# UICollectionView delete button

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView showing several items.  I also have an edit button in the screen toolbar.

How can I have delete icons appear on each UICollectionViewCell when I press the toolbar edit button?

There is very little in the way of examples on google at the moment, so if anyone can point me in the right direction, that would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Editing items in `UICollectionView`s aren't done the same way as they're done in a `UITableView`. In table views, there's a editing mode that'll show the delete button. But with collection views you gotta take care of that yourself.

Initially, I solved it this way:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {   
    if (self.editing) {
        // Open an action sheet with the possible editing actions
    }
}
```

But after that I removed the edit button and added a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to the `UICollectionView`. When long pressing an item I show the `UIActionSheet` that shows the possible actions.

One of those options might be a possibility for you.

Comment: Thanks GuidoH. I went down the UILongPressGestureRecognizer route, and that works great....... almost! How do I let the UIActionSheet know which collectionView cell was long pressed? I tried adding indexPath.row to the cell's tag, but as items are deleted, the tags are no longer correct. I tried [collectionView reloadData], but this caused some weird visual effects. Is there a better solution?

Comment: You can get the index path like this: `NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:[gesture locationInView:self.collectionView]];`. Guess you can make that work? :)

Comment: Longpress + actionsheet is the elegant way to do this. Thanks.

Comment: @GeneCode That's a nice way as well. It depends on your use case what fits better. If you're using editing mode, you won't need a long press for it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code defines what a cell in a collection view looks like. You can add a delete icon/button to the contentView of the cells that your data source provides.